# Thread causes program to crash

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am new to Android Development, but not new to Java.

One golden rule is to never block the GUI thread, nor the main thread.

The problem I am facing is that my app can send messages to a server, and the server displays the messages. When my server(PC) sends messages back to my android app, the app receives the message, and this is evident due to the `log method`.

The console, displays the message sent from the server, but the GUI app does not, this is because it freezes.

What I have done is set a thread, in side another thread. 
`Main Thread > Thread(Connects to server) > Thread (Listens for incoming messages) > Thread (The Android Gui Thread).

The problem here is; the program freezes and the activity stops responding. Butt the console window does display the messages sent from the server.

My question is, why is the app freezing, when I'm not blocking any threads?

```
private void ConnectButtonPress() {
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnConnect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnDisconnect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSend.setEnabled(true);
            enterET.setEnabled(true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        socket = new Socket(IPAddressET.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(portET.getText().toString()));  //connect to server
                        input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());

                        pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        pw.println(usersName);  //write the message to output stream
                        pw.flush();

                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                while (true){//this is where the problem is 
                                    try {
                                        input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    String message = input.nextLine();
                                    Log.i("LOL",message);
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            String message = input.nextLine();

                                            displayMessages.append(message +"\n");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();



                        //pw.close();
                        //pw.close();   //closing the connection
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();




        }
    });
}
```

Comment: By default in an Android app there is only one thread. Some people refer to it as the UI thread but that's a bad practice to get in to. Simply think of the single (main) thread as handling the main code execution and also anything which needs to be done with the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this block:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    String message = input.nextLine();

    displayMessages.append(message +"\n");
}
});
```

is run indefinitely inside the `while` loop, and hence blocks the main thread. Why do you need to build your `displayMessages` in the main thread? I guess you can just put `displayMessages.append(message +"\n");` inside your `while` loop.

Comment: So the `Android runOnUIThread` blocks the main thread? When the user gets a message back from the server, it updates the `message` to the `TextView`.

Comment: A  Oh I thought the Main thread, spawned off a UI thread. That is my bad. I will just test your answer.

Comment: First of all apologies for not tagging you, your name does not appear after `@`. I used the `runOnUIThread` because.... `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` Since I started a new thread on the `Main` thread, I can't `touch its views`

Comment: @Moynul that's correct, I just don't see any view changes inside that thread (inside any threads in your snippet, actually). E.g., if you'd called `mTextView.setText(message)` - this would have been "view touching", but I don't see any.

Comment: The problem lies in the `While(True)`, since it's a thread of it's own. I deleted the statements in the `while` block and it still froze. I removed the `while true` block and the app does not freeze. Other than this, the alternative would be do spawn a new thread from the main thread that listens for messages.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, `input.nextLine();` blocks the thread until a message is received from the server.

So, if I'm correct, when you receive a new message from the server, you run on the main thread to change the text view you have... but in the runOnUiThread you again call the `input.nextLine();`, when you already have read its value(`String message = input.nextLine();`), just before the `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...` call.

This basically causes, your main thread to wait for a new message from the server. You just have to use the value you already have, or, I suppose you can also play with the `hasNextLine()`.